# specificy different color for different strings in map pie charts in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a map with several pie charts on it in different locations.
My problem is that I'm adding each pie chart in a different iteration of a loop. The pie charts have some common but some different labels, so colours should not always be the same for each of the slices. Is there a way to add a parameter specifying which color should be used for a slice each time that each label appears??

In my code I'm trying to plot 10 pie charts (10 regions in the map) and in total I have 16 different label values (what I call haplogroup). In each iteration, I'm keeping the values for only one region to plot them, so that in each iteration the colors are restarted again...
I would like to add somenthing like the `par`section I've added, but it is not working...

I've seen that this could be done with `scale_color_manual` in ggplot2, but the function I'm using is not in the package and I think I should keep it...

`df_all`is a dataframe containing all the info that needs to be introduced in the pie charts. With the `grepl` I pick in each iteration the information for each region independantly and the pie slices should be filled with the Frequency column. Haplogroup should be the label. The main problem is that e.g. the colour for Haplogroup A is the same as in Haplogroup C (only because they are the first ones of each region, even if they are not the same). The dataframe looks like this (but bigger):

`Region Haplogroup Frequency
1    Region1    A      3
2    Region1    B      1
3    Region2    A      1
4    Region2    D      1
5    Region2    E      1
6    Region3    C      2
7    Region3    B      7
8    Region3    E      2
9    Region4    D      2`

The `coord` data frame contains two columns (x and y) with the coordinates where the pie chart should be placed in the map (each line corresponds to one of the Regions). The counter is a way to pick in each iteration the next coordinates corresponding to the next region. `coords` looks more or less like this:

`x      y
 1.3    14.3
 2.5    12.5
 1.9    10.4
 3.7    11.7`

In general, my code is this:

````
for (i in unique(df_all$Region)){
  counter=counter+1
  d <- df_all[grepl(i, df_all$Region),]
  print(d)
  add.pie(z=d$Frequency, x=coord$x[counter], y=coord$y[counter], radius = 0.005, 
          labels = d$Haplogroup)
    par(col = c("E1b1a7a" = "#A6CEE3", "E1b1a8"= "#428EBF", "R1b"= "#6CADA0",
                "A" = "#7CC171", "E1a" = "#66AB4C", "A3b2" = "#B89B74", "B" = "#E25E57",
                "B2" = "#EE6049", "B2a1" = "#F58242", "E" = "#F99F41", "E1b1" = "#ED8F47",
                "E1b1a" = "#BD93AD", "J1e" = "#9572AB", "L" = "#B19894", "T" = "#E9D27A", 
                "E1b1a7*" = "#B15928"))
}```


Thanks in advance for the help!
````

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a minimal version of `df_all` and `counter` and where `add.pie` comes from to make it reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

Start with everything in one data.frame, either by creating it manually:

```
df_all<-read.csv(text="
r, z, x, y,  l, c
1, 3, 3, 13, A,   red
1, 1, 3, 13, B,  blue
2, 1, 1, 12, A2,  pink
2, 2, 1, 12, B2, green
",header=T)
```

or by manipulating then binding your current data, eg. with `reshape::cast` on the coordinates, then `cbind`, etc.

You can manually enter colors with their english names (`df_all$c` above) or by adding columns with the hex colors your had or similar (`df_all$colorsm` below), or programatically based on some theme (shown).

```
library(mapplots)
df_all$colorzm= c("#A6CEE3", "#F58242", "#F99F41", "#ED8F47")#mannually
df_all$colorzp=  topo.colors(nrow(df_all))#programatically
```

Once you have everything together, you can use a simpler `lapply`:

```
plot(NA,NA, xlim=c(0,6), ylim=c(10,15) )
lapply(split(df_all,df_all$r),function(s){ #split by region
  add.pie(z=s$z, #your proportions
          x=s$x,
          y=s$y,
          labels=s$l, #your haplotypes
          col = s$colorzp)
})
```

Result:

[image]